# multiple processbuilder in a programme

Tags: java

i want to use two process builder in same program how can i do this both processbuilder are performing different task on same file how can i execute both together.

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "nusmv ", "inputfile.smv"); 
                Process p = pb.start();


ProcessBuilder pb123 = new ProcessBuilder("nusmv","-int","inputfile.smv");
            Process process123 = pb123.start();
```

it is just executing first processbuilder second one has been ignored.

Comment: Is pb.start() getting caught in an infinite loop?

Comment: it is just giving result of first process builder second one is ignored

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues which I can think of:
1. call process.waitFor() for the process so that each one gets completed before starting other.
2. Flush the output and error streams of one process before proceeding to the other.Many operating systems provide limited memory buffer for standard input and output streams. So if you do not flush or process the streams immediately they might cause the process to block or even deadlock.
For more info u can refer this link.
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html