# Multiple execution of a ProcessBuilder in a Java program

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to use  `ProcessBuilder` in a Java program which will be used many times in the same program. 
This code snippet is checked for every record in the database. If only one record satisfies the constraints like start time/end time then I don't have any problem, but if two records satisfies any of these constraints then first record, it executes the commands in the processbuilder and redirects output to logfile. Log but the second record, it doesn't executes the commands in the processbuilder and redirects output to the same logfile. There is a similar question about this problem in this site which has not been answered in the below link. I hope that atleast now anyone will go through this issue and give us a solution. I really don't understand where I am doing it wrong. Anyone who has idea about this concept please reply to this question and let me know where I am doing wrong.

[multiple processbuilder in a programme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812212/multiple-processbuilder-in-a-programme)

```
while(rs1.next())
        {
            instance_id = rs1.getString(1);
            startdate = rs1.getString(2);
            starttime = rs1.getString(3);
            endtime = rs1.getString(4);
            enddate = rs1.getString(5);
            if(presentdate.equals(startdate) || presentdate.equals(enddate))
            {
                if(presenttime.equals(starttime))
                {
                    String[] s1 = new String[]{"cmd", "/c","ec2-start-instances",instance_id,">>","D:\\logfile.log"};
                    ProcessBuilder builder1 = new ProcessBuilder(s1);
                    Process p1 = builder1.start();
                }
                else if(presenttime.equals(endtime))
                {
                    String[] s1 = new String[]{"cmd", "/c","ec2-stop-instances",instance_id,">>","D:\\logfile.log"};
                    ProcessBuilder builder1 = new ProcessBuilder(s1);
                    Process p1 = builder1.start();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use

```
p1.waitFor();
```

to sync this thread with the subprocess before starting another one, especially when they have a resource (`D:\logfile.log`) in common.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir. But I can't make the process wait, because my program has to check all the records from not single table but from 4 tables only in single minute and reloads if there are any records scheduled at that particular time. Is there any other way to solve this issue??

Comment: So for example if there are 100 records scheduled at that time, practically it will be not possible to wait for each record within that one minute. Please suggest me how this problem can be resolved.

Comment: You may have to read standard output from the Process, which may require one thread per executing process. OTOH, it may be possible to generate a single script containing all cmd invocations and, after iterating the DB relation (rs1), execute this as a single subprocess.

Comment: However, I think it would be enlightening to check that my suggestion (i.e., to waitFor) avoids the issue you have been reporting. Then proceed with one of the other options.

Comment: Thank you sir, p.waitFor(); helping me to get the required output but took few seconds to load the page completely. This process works absolutely fine for less records.But as I  mentioned if there are 100 records scheduled at the same time then it will be a issue to load whole content in one minute.

Comment: Yet another idea I had: collect all of the commands first, and then execute the subprocesses, one after the other. It seems to me that you have one minute until the program has to do another pass through that relation.

Comment: Yes my program need to be refreshed for every minute. collecting all the commands and executing at once is not possible I guess because for each iteration in the while loop instance_id changes, please look into my code in the string array. so executing each command when its turn comes is proper way. If you can suggest me any other idea it would be very helpful.

Comment: can we use fileHandler in the place of processbuilder? I mean can we use fileHandler in place of processbuiler so that we can skip p1.waitFor() method..

Comment: You need to create a process for *running* those cmd executions. You could drop the ">> D:\\logfile.log" from these commands and create log entries from the Java program. (If I understood you correctly.)

Comment: So you are saying that using log4j package to create log entries instead of taking the output of that command directly to the logfile, Is that what you mean? can we write any message we want to put in the logfile or only debug/error/fatal/etc level predefined messages into logfiles using log4j package?

Comment: Anything can be written.

Comment: process.waitFor() is helping me to get the output, but as I mentioned above it has some delay issue too. If no instances scheduled at that time it has 5 seconds delay for every start of the application and if at all any instances scheduled at that time it will take even more seconds and it can be a minute also if 100 records are scheduled at the same time. it will skip few minutes if this happens. Which is not at all good. Can you help me sort out this problem. My application should not have delay(this is the requirement). Please do reply. Thank you.

Comment: Let me repeat my suggestion: to collect all commands in a single script ("batch file") executable by cmd.exe and execute this with a single process. Thus, log file entries are appended one after another.